# How to Delete string in parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

that is mys string: France (Republic of France)
I want to get only France and delete string in parameter.

```
France (Republic of France)
```

How to do it ?
thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? This isn't a free write-my-code service. Try a regular expression, for instance.

Comment: You also need to be clear about your question. In your string, there are two instances of string 'France'... which one exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this code should help you.

```js
const str = "France (Republic of France)";
const str2 = "Costa Rica (country Costa Rica)";
const str3 = "United States of America";

function getCountryNameFromStr(str) {
  var pattern = /(.*?)( \(.*?\))/gi;
  var match = pattern.exec(str);
  return match !== null ? match[1] : str;
}

console.log(getCountryNameFromStr(str));
console.log(getCountryNameFromStr(str2));
console.log(getCountryNameFromStr(str3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` this string by whitespace and then get the first element of the resultant array (it will be the first word only):

```js
const str = "France (Republic of France)";
const stringFinal = str.split(" ")[0];
console.log(stringFinal);
```